# After turning an excel file into a dictionary, how do I return "none" for the keys and values not in the dictionary?

Tags: python, excel, file, return, nonetype

I already imported the excel file and everything; it is able to distinguish between a state and capital, but if i enter some arbitrary string such as 'fdajfja' in for either variable that I defined, it just returns an error when I want it to return "none".
Here is the code

```
d= {}
d1= {}

with file as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        (key, val) = line.split(",")
        d[str(key)]=val
        d1[str(val)]=key

def findCapital(state):
    return d[state]

def findState(capital):
    return d1[capital]
```

how do I insert this into my code correctly?

```
else:
    return None
```

Comment: Use `return d.get(state, "none")` and `return d1.get(capital, "none")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d = {}
d1 = {}

with file as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split(",")
        d[str(key)] = val
        d1[str(val)] = key

def findCapital(state):
    return d.get(state)

def findState(capital):
    return d1.get(capital)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the value exists in the dictionary.

```
if d.has_key(): 
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

to return none you can check if an keyvalue is in the dictionary with **in**

```
if key in dict:
    return dict[key]
else:
    return None
```